# Loading pdf or url in Android Webview

Tags: android, pdf, webview, android-webview

I am working on an Android application that opens urls its content is HTML or Pdf ... I used this way to open it

```
WebView webView = (WebView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.web_view);
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

// This is the url that may be .html or .pdf
String url = "https://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/1/119.html";
//String url = "https://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/11/1124.html";

webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        if (progress >= 100) {
            setContentShown(true);
        }
    }
});
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

the first url opens normally in the webview, but the second url doesn't show anything in the webview .. and If I try to open it on the browser it redirects me to this url [https://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/11/p1124.pdf] and open normally.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question? `WebView` itself does not display PDFs.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, I want to open the two types of url .html or .pdf in the webview

Comment: As I wrote, `WebView` itself does not display PDFs. You are welcome to experiment with stuff like `pdf.js` for displaying PDF files in `WebView`, but `WebView` does not have built-in PDF rendering capabilities.

Comment: But the problem is that I have a large number of urls .. and I don't know which one will redirect to be .pdf and which one will be .html, So how Can I solve that problem ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a download listener to your webview. Inside the listener, you can choose to download the PDF by overriding its methods.

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new (DownloadListener listener) { // is it a pdf? });
```

Comment: But I don't want to download the pdf, I want to open it in the webview.

Comment: Webview in Android can display web pages, images, and text. It can't display PDFs. So, in the Download listener, you concatenate the PDF URL to the Google Docs viewer URL and load it in the webview.

Comment: The problem is that I have a lot of urls some of them open html and others open pdf, and I am not able to differentiate between them.

Comment: You implement the DownloadListener. When a URL with a PDF is opened, the DownloadListener's methods will be called. In that method, you can check the extension and if it is a PDF, then load it in WebView by appending the PDF URL to the Google Docs link ("http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=")

Comment: The only problem is that the pdf url comes in .html extension something like that ( https://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/11/1124.html ) if you tried to open it to the browser it redirects you to a .pdf url. My problem comes here. I can't catch the redirected url.

Comment: Those URLs will change to those ending with PDF in the DownloadListener methods. You don't have to manually process each link. Webview will handle it. You just implement the methods.